# Haproxy set Host Header per origin Server

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, backend

We are trying to set host header per origin server, we can set per back end, but we are using default names on Azure app services, and as such the service will only respond to its own hostname, for example

http-request set-header Host example1.azurewebsites.net # for origin server 1

http-request set-header Host example2.azurewebsites.net # for origin server 2

However, can't see any way to set this on the origin server itself

server svr_example1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none

server svr_example2 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none

Something like

server svr_example1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none http-request set-header Host example1.azurewebsites.net

server svr_example2 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 11 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none http-request set-header Host example2.azurewebsites.net

Using haproxy version 1.8.28

Answer (score 0):

They are separate directives and you must put them on separate lines, e.g.:

```
backend svr_example1
        server svr_example1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none
        http-request set-header Host example1.azurewebsites.net
```

Note that you can only do this when HAProxy terminates TLS. You cannot do this if you are passing through TLS.

Comment: This doesn't work as we need to origin servers each with a distinct hostname

backend svr_example1

        server svr_example1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none

        http-request set-header Host example1.azurewebsites.net

server svr_example2 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 id 10 weight 10 maxconn 25 cookie exa1 check ssl verify none

        http-request set-header Host example2.azurewebsites.net


Sadly only the last hostname is used, which results in a 404 from the Azure webapp (Domain must match)

Comment: @Jay You will have to use different backends, and it sounds like you really should be doing that anyway.

Comment: We would if we could, but from the FE side they use the same domain name, its only due to the way azure app services is setup that we need to supply a different host header.

Comment: @Jay https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, ended up implementing @Michael H suggesting with a twist, using 2 backends each with their own origin server and header information and then in the Front End using nbsrv to decide if the BE is valid and make a decision from there.

```
    acl beExampleDead1 nbsrv(S_be_Example1) lt 1
    acl beExampleDead2 nbsrv(S_be_Example1) lt 1
```

And then use the acl as part of the rule to decide on back end

Jay